# Why extension methods for Blazor's ComponentBase class are only available trough this?

Tags: razor, blazor, .net-5, blazor-webassembly

I needed to extend all the Blazor components with a couple of convenient methods (doesn't matter why, just some project-specific stuff).

I'm not sure if it is the only way to do it in Blazor, but I decided to use the good old extension methods:

```
public static class ComponentBaseExtensions
{
    public static string MyMethod(this ComponentBase component, ...)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Everything went fine, except one annoying issue: these extension methods are only awailable if I call them through `this`, i.e. that code is valid:

```
<div class="@this.MyMethod()"></div>
```

and this one isn't:

```
<div class="@MyMethod()"></div>
```

So, the question is: why it behaves like that and how to get rid of it (if possible) to make the razor templates cleaner?

Answer (score 1):

> I needed to extend all the Blazor components with a couple of convenient methods

Then you could use inheritance. Add a base class

```
 class MyComponentBase : ComponentBase 
 { 
   protected string MyMethod(int x) { }
 }
```

and on top of all relevant pages:

```
 @inherits MyComponentBase

    ... MyMethod(7);
```

Comment: Yep, I thought about that, but in that case I'll loose the possibility to inherit my components from another components (for example third-party) and use them the same way as MyComponentBase (that's actually why I used the extension methods).

Answer (score 0):

Got it now: it's actually absolutely normal C# behavior, looks like `I just wanted` it to work in a special way in context of razor templates.
So, the question is a bit stupid, but maybe it'll help to someone who will be confused the same way as me :-)

Comment: Please, edit or remove your question...